# Acceleration derivative

Tags: kinematics, notation, differentiation

I am reading Morris Kline's "Calculus" and I fail to understand this notation:

> We have acceleration to which an object $r$ feet from the center of the earth (and above the earth) is subject. If we take $r$ to be positive in the upward direction, then, because the acceleration causes a downward motion and therefore a downward velocity and so $a$ decrease in $r$, we must write
>   $$a=-\frac{GM}{r^2}$$
>   Moreover, $a$ is the second derivative of $r$ with respect to $t$. To remind ourselves of the variables involved, we use Leibnizian notation and write
>   $$\frac{d^2r}{dt^2}=-\frac{GM}{r^2}=\frac{dv}{dt}.$$

I don't understand why the speed in this formula is a derivative with respect to $t$. From $$a=-\frac{GM}{r^2}$$ I can clearly see, that acceleration is only dependent on $r$, so why can't I write $$\frac{dv}{dr}=-\frac{GM}{r^2}~?$$
And in general how can I know what the derivative of a function is with respect to?

Comment: Your last equation is dimensionally incorrect.

Comment: Why *should* you be able to write your last equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Because by definition acceleration is change in velocity over time**. The fact that acceleration is a function of radius changes **nothing**. Basically what the equation says is that **acceleration as a function of radius** is equal to some formula. We then know from the definition of acceleration that it is change in velocity over time. If this helps clear it up:
$$a(r) = \frac{dv}{dt}(r) = -\frac{GM}{r^2}$$
The next step is simply recognising that $r$ is related to the displacement so again by definition acceleration is the second derivative of $r$ over time. So basically the issue here is not about understanding what to derive an equation in relation to, it is about understanding that acceleration is by definition the change in velocity over time and no mathematical operation is applied to get this result and that the relationship between acceleration and velocity is independent of the variables they are expressed in terms of.

Answer (score 0):

Acceleration is *defined* as the derivative of velocity with respect to $t$:

$$a=\frac{dv}{dt}$$

It is the instantaneous change of velocity. Just like velocity is defined as the instantaneous change of position $r$:

$$v=\frac{dr}{dt}$$

If you agree that:

$$a=-\frac{GM}{r^2}$$

then it is a simple thing to exchange $a$ with its definition $dv/dt$.

Answer (score 0):

The velocity is **always**, by *definition*, the derivative of the position $\textbf{r}(t)$ with respect to the time and likewise for the acceleration
$$
\textbf{v}(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\textbf{r}(t),\qquad \textbf{a}(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\textbf{v}(t)=\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\textbf{r}(t).
$$
The position is, in turn, always a function of the time, although often not explicitly mentioned. Your formula is to be intended as:
$$
a(r(t))=-\frac{GM}{r(t)^2}=\frac{d^2}{dt^2}r(t)=\frac{d}{dt}v(t)
$$
from which you can calculate position and velocity by solving the differential equations. It is unfortunate common practice for textbooks to not explicitly state the time dependences of the quantities and this usually generates confusion. Nevertheless always remember how the quantities are defined in the first place, which helps you digging out what the correct variables to derive with respect to are. In the cases at hand, in particular in classical mechanics, cinematic quantities are defined as derivatives with respect to the time, *always* and under all circumstances. The scenario changes when you move to special relativity, wherein the invariances have to be calculated with respect to the space-time path length $s$ because time depends itself on the reference frame, but I guess this is not what you are asking for in this place.